# Jquery (this) selector help

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="pic.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
```

I am trying to select the div and the child image both at the same time. I need to use $(this) to select the div. I know I can use $(this).children() or $(this).find('img') to get the image. Is there a way to select both the div and image using $(this) for the div.

Comment: What function are you trying to perform on them both? Some context might help us answer the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `$(this).find('img').andSelf()` ?

Comment: or something like `$(this).find("img").add(this)` should work